# When should a post be deleted?

Tags: discussion

This question was inspired by this deleted answer: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/59184/4555 .  The answer was both correct, and sourced with a link.  In fact, it was better than the existing answers. I was actually planning on providing the same answer, until I saw it had already been deleted twice.

In this case it was also a new contributor.  It was deleted, without comment, by a moderator (@GeoffreyThomas). **This is not a good way to be welcoming to new members.**  In my opinion, downvotes, helpful comments, and edits should all be tried before deletion (except in the case of bad faith posts, abusive posts or spam).  Deletion should be a last resort for a truly irredeemable post.  And, if a good faith post is deleted, a comment should always be provided.

*Note: I have edited this question to make it less specific to a particular post, and more general.*

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it is because it is literally a bad word-by-word copy from wikipedia - without disclosure and proper quoting or sourcing.

Failing to add any content or context to a source or to properly indicate which content is not your own may very well lead to deletion.

In other words: It is one thing to deliver a sourced answer. It is another one to simply copy a source without proper sourcing, even if a badly formatted link to that source is given.

Comment: That makes sense.  However, I'd suggest that comments for improving the answer, or edits would be a better, less off-putting way to address the defects.  I can't think of anything less welcoming to a new poster than having a well intentioned post deleted without any feedback.